# sqlalchemy db.create_all problem when i try to use the function in the python cli

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Ok, so I have my tables, laid out with the **repr** class definitions, and I get this error when I try to use `db.create_all()` in python

```
sqlalchemy.exc.NoReferencedTableError: Foreign key associated with column 'subuser_table.userid' could not find table 'usersTable' with which to generate a foreign key to target column 'userid'
```

My code is shown below:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class usersTable(db.Model):
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    joined = db.Column(db.Date, nullable=False)
    package = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    subuser = db.relationship('Subuser', backref='user', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"users_table({self.fname}, {self.lname}, {self.email}, {self.username}, {self.password}, {self.joined}, {self.package})"

class subuserTable(db.Model):
    userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users_table.userid'), nullable=False)
    subid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String, unique=True, nullable=False)
    password = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    fname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    lname = db.Column(db.String, nullable=False)
    admin = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"subuser_table({self.fname}, {self.lname}, {self.email}, {self.username}, {self.password}, {self.joined}, {self.package})"
```

I do have my URI in another file, and it does link to the database correctly.  I just can't get these tables to be created due to the contraint error.  If anyone has any ideas please let me know

Comment: The error and the provided code do not seem to match. You have `db.ForeignKey('users_table.userid')`, but the error states that you would have `db.ForeignKey('usersTable.userid')`.

Comment: I got it fixed, there was an artifact left over in another file

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There was an artifact left over in another file that I didnt change the name of.  The error didnt really help, check your files!